# Sonar 3.5.1/sonar-runner 2.2 fails with BadDatabaseVersion

Tags: configuration, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have installed Sonar 3.5.1 on a brand new PostgreSQL 9.2 database. The server seems to run fine, but sonar-runner (v2.2) fails with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.sonar.core.persistence.BadDatabaseVersion: The current batch process and the configured remote server do not share the same DB configuration.
    - Batch side: jdbc:postgresql://10.1.0.210/sonar (postgres / *****)
    - Server side: check the configuration at http://sonar.kopitoto/system
```

I am pretty confident that there is no other concurrent installation of Sonar pointing to the same database, because:

- This is the first Sonar installation in this organization, ever
- The value of `sonar.core.id` in the DB matches the value returned by the Sonar server:

Getting the value from the DB:

```
sonar=# SELECT text_value FROM properties WHERE prop_key = 'sonar.core.id';
   text_value   
----------------
 20130525192736
(1 row)
```

Getting the value from the server:

```
$ curl http://sonar.kopitoto/api/server
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server>
  <id>20130525192736</id>
  <version>3.5.1</version>
  <status>UP</status>
</server>
```

Sonar-runner's properties:

```
sonar.host.url: http://sonar.kopitoto
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
sonar.jdbc.password: *****
sonar.jdbc.schema: public
sonar.jdbc.url: jdbc:postgresql://10.1.0.210/sonar
sonar.jdbc.username: postgres
```

Of course, the password is not five stars, but I checked it twice. If I change it a little bit, the runner fails earlier with authentication error. So a password mismatch is ruled out.

Server's `sonar.properties`:

```
sonar.jdbc.username:                       postgres
sonar.jdbc.password:                       *****
sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:postgresql://10.1.0.210/sonar
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                org.postgresql.Driver
sonar.jdbc.schema:                         public
```

Again, the password above is not five stars, but I am pretty sure it is correct. The server logs say nothing about errors, and shows how the database schema is initialized when I stop the thing, drop the database, create an empty one, and then start the Sonar server again.

Am I missing something?

At this point, I am thinking that this is a bug in Sonar (probably in sonar-runner). Unfortunately, Sonar's issue-tracking system is littered with such reports, all closed with "Not a bug" resolution. I guess I will be dismissed similarly if I reopen one of those issues.

So I hope I am really missing something here.

Comment: The JIRA issue SONAR-3685 suggests it's an issue with the install. Have you checked the server logs? Are you certain the database was created/upgraded without issue? Perhaps try a fresh install on a new database to disprove this theory

Comment: I wasn't upgrading from a previous install. I am doing a completely new fresh install from scratch. Before writing this question, I dropped the database twice just to see it recreated again without errors in the server logs.

Comment: Hi Kaloian, I've tried to reproduce your issue locally, but as I expected I could not. Your configuration looks correct, so I'm currently running out of ideas... Can you manage to make it work with a default install? (using H2 as a DB - thus with no additional config relating to database)

Comment: Hi Fabrice, thank you very much for your time. I just tried to use H2 as you suggested, but got the same result: `BadDatabaseVersion`. Well, this is really weird. I'll try to debug sonar-runner to check what values of `sonar.core.id` it actually sees from both sources.

Comment: I added an extra message in `DatabaseCompatibility.java` to show the two ids that are actually compared. It spits out the following: `sonar.core.id DB: '20130527195003'`, `sonar.core.id SERVER: ''`. The sonar.core.id received from the server is an empty String.

Comment: I found the curlpit. I am actually hit by [SONAR-3579](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3579), which was fixed in version 3.2 but there is obviosuly a regression. After applying the workaround, everything works fine.

Comment: Great that you found the issue. Can you answer your own question here on Stackoverflow so that people who face this issue will quickly see the answer?

Comment: It would be even more useful if [SONAR-3579](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3579) is reopened and fixed again. I didn't had any misconfiguration on my part. This is a bug in Sonar.